# Compass Line Number Comments Not Showing Up with Gulp

Tags: css, sass, gulp, compass

I am attempting to make the switch from GruntJS to Gulp and have run into a problem with my Gulp task for processing my SASS files via Compass. The files compile just fine into the single CSS file as they did under my GruntJS implementation, but I am missing the line number comments that show me where the CSS rules come from such as:
    /* line 26, ../_components/sass/_base.scss */

The code from my gulpfile.js for the task is:

```
gulp.task('compass', function() {
   gulp.src(sassSources)
     .pipe(compass({
        comments: true,
        sass: '_components/sass', 
        image: 'builds/dev/images',
        style: 'nested'
   })
   .on('error', gutil.log))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('builds/dev/css'))
});
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful with `gulp-compass`, it is not a gulp plugin (albeit named so) and has been blacklisted by the Gulp community for quite a while. It does not what Gulp plugins are supposed to do (e.g. it's possible to run them without `gulp.src` and `gulp.dest`), and other plugins are already doing its work perfectly fine. One of those plugins is `gulp-ruby-sass`. This setup might work for you:

```
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
gulp.task('compass', function() {
   return sass(sassSources, {
     compass: true,
     lineNumbers: true
   }).on('error', gutil.log))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('builds/dev/css'))
});
```

This uses `gulp-ruby-sass` which is able to run with the `compass` extension. You see that I activated `lineNumbers` here to give you said output.

I see from your Gulpfile that you might have some extension requiring some `image`s, I don't know exactly what that does, but if it's mandatory to your setup, you might better call compass directly (the command line tool) using `require('child_process').exec(...)`

Comment: The images setting was just copied from the tutorial video and just is something I have always put into the compass configuration be it in the Grunt/Gulp files or in config.rb.

Thanks for the help. I will make the change to the gulpfile.js and continue my conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You should add **sass_options = { :line_numbers => true }** to your config.rb file even if gulp-compass module doesn't support lineNumbers as an option.

important part of config.rb file

```
css_dir = 'app/assets/style/'
sass_dir = 'app/assets/style/sass/'
images_dir = 'app/assets/image/'
javascripts_dir = 'app/assets/script/'
sass_options = { :line_numbers => true }
```

And your gulp task should look like this

important part of gulpfile.js file

```
return gulp.src('./app/assets/style/sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(plugins.compass({
      config_file: './config.rb', // if you don't use a config file , you should start using immediately
      css: './app/assets/style/',
      sass: './app/assets/style/sass/',
      image: './app/assets/image/',
      line_comments: true,
      sourcemap: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/assets/style/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble generating the line number comments using **gulp-compass** also.  I tried a lot of things including matching all the plugin versions to the sample code I used to even completely discarding my code and use the full [sample](https://github.com/planetoftheweb/workflows) instead to no avail.

On top of its lack of compliance with gulp standards as @ddprrt suggested, **gulp-compass** seems to be broken now.  Besides generating a stylesheet on the destination folder, it also generates another under the **{app_root}/css** folder.  I suspect, the latter is some sort of caching, but that functionality is currently broken.  As can be seen [here](https://github.com/shapeous/wf/blob/master/builds/development/css/style.css), if you delete that stylesheet and re-run the task, the line number comments will finally show up.  Below, I automated this by installing and using the **gulp-clean-dest** plugin.  I have no tried using other plugins, but this hack handles the issue.

```
var gulp      = require("gulp")
  , compass   = require("gulp-compass")
  , cleanDest = require("gulp-clean-dest")
  ;

gulp.task("compass", function() {
  gulp.src("components/sass/style.scss")
    .pipe(compass(
      {  "sass":  "components/sass"
      ,  "image":  "builds/development/images"
      ,  "style":  "expanded"
      ,  "comments":  true
      })
      .on("error", gutil.log)
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest("builds/development/css"))
    .pipe(cleanDest("css"))
});
```