# Gulp-compass not compiling sass to css

Tags: sass, gulp, compass, gulp-compass

```
gulp.task('compass', function() {
    gulp.src('components/sass/styles.scss')
    .pipe(compass({ 
        config_file: 'config.rb',
        css: 'builds/development/css',
        sass: 'components/sass', 
        image: 'builds/development/images'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('builds/development/css')) });
```

Here I am trying to run gulp compass in command prompt.. its executing but not producing the output in the desired destination.. please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here: [Compass Line Number Comments Not Showing Up with Gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269355/compass-line-number-comments-not-showing-up-with-gulp/)

Be careful with `gulp-compass`, it is not a gulp plugin (albeit named so) and has been blacklisted by the Gulp community for quite a while. It does not what Gulp plugins are supposed to do (e.g. it's possible to run them without `gulp.src` and `gulp.dest`), and other plugins are already doing its work perfectly fine. One of those plugins is `gulp-ruby-sass`. This setup might work for you:

```
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
gulp.task('compass', function() {
   return sass(sassSources, {
     compass: true
   }).on('error', gutil.log))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('builds/dev/css'))
});
```

This uses `gulp-ruby-sass` which is able to run with the `compass` extension.